# Regex to strip email subaddressing (dots and +wildcards)

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to remove gmail subaddressing, i.e.: strip dots and +whatever from gmail addresses.

for example:
`e.m.a..i.laddress+wha.t+e..ver@gmail.com -> emailaddress@gmail.com`

- all dots before the @ should be gone.
- everything from the first + to the @ should be gone.

I can do it with excel, but I am trying to do it only with regex, i.e. match all the characters that should be removed.

`=concat(replace(REGEXREPLACE(left(A1,find("@",A1)-1),"\.",""),find("+",REGEXREPLACE(left(A1,find("@",A1)-1),"\.","")),len(REGEXREPLACE(left(A1,find("@",A1)),"\.",""))-find("+",REGEXREPLACE(left(A1,find("@",A1)-1),"\.","")),""),right(A1,len(A1)-find("@",A1)+1))`

The domain part should stay intact.

Comment: Please state which regex engine / language you are using. Not all regexs are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my try on this: `(\.(?=[^@]*?@)|\+[^@]*?(?=@))`
You can see a working demo [here](https://regexr.com/47fpg).
The expression matches everything you want to remove. It uses lookaheads with arbitrary quantifiers - i hope the regex engine you are using supports this.
Maybe there's also a solution without those, but that's what i can offer for now.

EDIT: I changed the expression so it's not using the evil `.*?` anymore.

Comment: After your change it matches also the dots in the domain.

Comment: @user3006799 That's weird. It shouldn't to that. In the demo it works, too. Are you sure?

Comment: You're right. It works. It matched the dots in the subdomain only when I added new lines with more examples of emails.